# Change Default White for Zero On Contour Plot in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, contour

How can I change the default white for zero for the output of a contour plot to a different color in MATLAB?

```
longitude = [80 82 95]
latitude = [30 32 35]
temp = [0 0 0; 0 0 0; 0 0 0]
contourf(longitude,latitude,temp)
```

Thanks,

Amanda

Comment: see the help for `colormap` or `caxis` to see if they are useful.

Comment: running your example throws the warning that `contourf` won't draw anything. Is that intentional?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The key seems to be in the "renderer/rendering" mode from the figure properties. It must be set to either 'painters' or 'zbuffer'. I am not an expert and I didn't understand how to set it by default. I changed it manually through the figure editor (click on the outer figure frame --> More properties --> Renderer) and then I clicked "generate code" from the menu bar to make a function that automatically creates all plots in the same way.